# Changing Max Client Protocol in smb.conf

Tags: bash, smb

I have a bunch of CentOS computers for which I would like to change the smb.conf to either enable `client max protocol = SMB2` by uncommenting it or by adding it in of it doesn't exist under the [global] section.

Is there any way to script this? Its quite a couple computers that this change will have to be executed on and I'd like to pair it with another bash script so this maintenance doesn't take too much time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With `sed`: delete all lines which contain `client max protocol =` and then replace `[global]` by `[global]\nclient max protocol = SMB2`.

Comment: So don't use the append mode but replace it instead?

Comment: "I have a bunch of CentoS computers ..." Use a configuration management tool.